# codeigniter app not working when xampp default localhost port changed

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, database-connection

Application developed in codeigniter working fine on http://localhost. But on another system it is not running with port http://localhost:83. Though phpmyadmin, xampp default dashboard all working fine. Even apps with no db also working fine. Below is code from database.php in config folder

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost:83',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => 'password',
'database' => 'app_db',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => FALSE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

);

what could be the issue. Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "not running" exactly? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: it keep going on trying to load page than gives message "This page isn;t working" localhost is currently unable to handly this requrest HTTP Error 500

Comment: You don't have to mention port number in database settings, just remove it. You misunderstood with apache server port and mysql port numbers.

Comment: Then look in the server error logs. There's going to be a specific error message there. No point guessing (nor asking others on Stack Overflow to guess.)

Comment: Thanks kishor. It worked after removing port number in database.php. I did it before but don't know whey it didn't work before. Now although the login page is appearing but after giving ID and Pwd it is not logging in even giving correct correct credentials. I belief this is also some issue of localhost  setting somewhere. If you have any idea plz share. Thanks